# Undefined reference error during building the code for a couple of statement functions

Tags: function, build, module, fortran, fortran90

I am receiving "**Undefined reference error to ...**" errors for a couple of statement functions while building my code. It compiles successfully.

My program section of code starts with the below statement functions after defining the necessary parameter and dimensions. In addition, I have other functions/subroutines in the `CONTAINS` section of the module.

```
        PROGRAM ......
        DIMENSIONS bla bla

        !***** FUNCTIONS *****
        !***FREE ENERGIES PER VOLUME OF INDIVIDUAL PHASES

        FL(X)=((1.-X)*GCU_L+R*T*((1.-X)*DLOG(1.-X)))
        DFI(X)=2.*CC*(X-0.435)/VM

        *****************************
        VM=20.65D-6  
        R=8.3145     
        T=250. + 273.  
        TEMP=T
        GCU_L=5194.277+120.973331*T

        bla bla 

        END PROGRAM
```

Build errors that I am receiving:

```
  gfortran -Wall -o "123456" "123456.f90" (in directory: /Geany)
  /tmp/ccwapaHQ.o: In function `__mymodule_MOD_fsteady':
  123456.f90:(.text+0x7e3a): undefined reference to `fl_'
  123456.f90:(.text+0x7ea9): undefined reference to `dfi_'
  **DELETED THE REST**
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  Compilation failed.
```

I thought copying the statement functions to contain section of my MODULE may solve the errors. However, it produces the following compilation errors...

```
      gfortran -Wall -c "123456.f90" (in directory: /Geany)
      Compilation failed.
      123456.f90:523.127:
      FL(X)=((1.-X)*GCU_L+R*T*((1.-X)*DLOG(1.-X)))
                                           1

      DFI(X)=2.*CC*(X-0.435)/VM
                                 1
      Error: Unexpected STATEMENT FUNCTION statement in CONTAINS section at (1)
      123456.f90:1332.16:
        USE myModule
            1
      Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mymodule.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

Comment: I guess that in the first case you have a reference to `fl` in the procedure `fsteady` in module `mymodule`.  Can you confirm, show that?

Comment: Yes. you are right. What should I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to say is that statement functions are obsolescent in current Fortran, and I'd suggest that you consider avoiding their use.

However, your first sub-question isn't really specific to statement functions, but scope.  Your functions are declared/defined in the main program: you can't expect them to be available in a module which is use associated by that program any more than you'd expect a variable to be.  Use association goes the other way, making entities in the module available in the main program (or other thing using the module).

Statement functions differ a little from internal procedures in that they can't be actual arguments to a procedure reference in a module.  You could pass a "proper" function `contain`ed in the main program to a module procedure, just not a statement function.

Your attempt to move the statement functions into the module itself is the second sub-question.  You cannot define a statement function in a module.  It cannot be before the `contains` statement and it cannot be after (in the standard these are covered by a restriction each).

It's hard to see that you will lose anything by changing your statement function in the main program to a full function of the module (after the `contains`).

Comment: Well one can have a statement function in a module, but only inside a contained procedure.  Not "naked".

Comment: Thank you. You answered many of the questions I had in my mind. I understand all your paragraphs, except the 3rd one. Moreover, I realized sometimes people use **CONTAIN** anywhere outside the modules and I don't know what this means...

Comment: `contains` elsewhere introduce _internal procedures _ which can be passed around (in a F2008 way).  You can see a question about that from recently.